# creating a character array with gff file

Tags: arrays, matlab

Could someone please help me with creating a "character array" with this sort of data:
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/genomes/Bacteria/Escherichia_coli_ATCC_8739_uid58783/NC_010468.gff

Instruction from our collaborator:

One can copy and paste a gff file into a character array by  typing gff={} and then copy and “paste excel data”

But I can somehow only save it as a cell array and hence the script downstream can't run properly.

***additional info***
I need to use the .gff file in a .m script (that I got from someone else) to parse my sequences. 
Here's the part of my script that I *think* pertains to my question:

```
genelist=gff(:,3);
starts=gff(:,4);
ends=gff(:,5);
names=gff(:,9);
genelogical=strncmp('gene',genelist,4);
```

Therefore I want 9 columns with information like this:
1. seqID; 
2. source; 
3. type; 
4&5. start and end; 
6. score; 
7. strand; 
8. phase
9. attributes

Also when I saved the cell array as "cell", and tried to convert it into a character array by typing

```
char(cell)
```

I got this error message:
cell elements must be character arrays
So guess that doesn't work...

***edit over***

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks,
Joyce

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise and strip down the problem? How do the data look? What do you want to do with the character array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions you were given are referring to the following context menu item accessible from the "Variables" editor:

[image]

First, run at the command line `gff={};` to make an empty `cell` array. Then double click the `gff` variable in the Workspace tab to get the above editor window. Click on the square regino to the top left of the table to select all cells, then right click to get the displayed menu, and paste the data.  You should end up with the following if the paste worked correctly (it could actually take a couple of minutes - check CPU usage):

[image]

Then the commands you posted work.  The `strncmp` says definitively that as cell array is needed.

Comment: Thanks chappjc, your codes work, but I think I didn't specify the problem well enough. I will edit my post and it'd be great to have your input. Joyce

Comment: @user2972177: The instructions indicate you need a cell array to perform those operations.  I updated my answer and attached a screenshot of the "Paste Excel Data" menu item that you should use.